# How can I enable the finger print scanner on an HP 4540 in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, fingerprint

I have an HP 4540S and installed all drivers, software security, but the finger print scanner on my laptop does not work in Windows 8.

Comment: W8 Tutorial here....http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/Guide-to-the-Notebook-Fingerprint-Sensor/m-p/1808263

Answer (score 1):

From HP's forums [HP Probook 4540s: Fingerprint Scanner Not Working](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-e-g-Windows-8/HP-Probook-4540s-Fingerprint-Scanner-Not-Working/m-p/1767649#M78819):

- Open HP Protect tools.
- Then go to administration in the bottom right corner -> Administrative Console -> Increase System security.
- Tick Windows login security.

Comment: Hi, i've already installed latest version of .NET but when i try to install HP ProtectTools it's given me error .NET 3.5 version is required.